# Weird behavior using PHP sessions

Tags: php

I guess I am doing something wrong here but I don't see exactly what.

### PHP Function `session_active`

```
function session_active()
{
  return false;
}
```

### index.html

```
  <?php
  if (session_active) { ?>

    // main index shown

  <?php } else { ?>

    // login shown

  <?php } ?>
```

### Problem

Even when `session_active()` returns false, the main index is shown.

`session_active()` was longer originally but always returned true so as a test I stripped it down and made it return false, but it still shows true.

Comment: what do you know about sessinos? What do you know about function invocation?

Comment: If this is literally your code, you're missing the `()` to *invoke* the function. This also is not really about sessions at all with the code you show, just about functions.

Comment: shouldn't you cal it like `session_active()`, i.e. with the parenthesis

Comment: You are missing function brackets ()

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to add `()` with your function

```
 <?php
  if (session_active()) { ?>

    // main index shown

  <?php } else { ?>

    // login shown

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: And that's why you would enable error reporting. You'd catch the error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the parenthesis on your if :

```
if( session_active() )
```